# Printing out values from a function

Tags: python-2.7

Ok so the issue with my program is that for some reason when I run it the variables at the bottom come out as "None" instead of the count of the amount of ATG's in the original strings of HumanDNA, MouseDNA, and UnknownDNA. I couldn't add the part where i define these DNA's because of their length and was difficult for me to add it. How can I change it so instead it outputs the amount of times the substring is found in the original string as a variable that is outside the function and can output it in the format I have at the bottom.

```
def countCodon(string, substring):
    i = string.find(substring)

def compareDNA(string1, string2):
    string1 = raw_input("Enter string 1: ")
    string2 = raw_input("Enter string 2: ")
    Hamming = 0
        for ch1, ch2 in zip(string1, string2):
                if ch1 != ch2:
                        Hamming += 1
    l = len(string1)
    similarity_score = ((l - Hamming)/(l))
    print similarity_score


HD = countCodon(humanDNA, "ATG")
MD = countCodon(mouseDNA, "ATG")
UD = countCodon(unknownDNA, "ATG") 
print "Mouse: ", HD
print "Human: ", MD
print "Unknown: ", UD

MU = compareDNA(mouseDNA, unknownDNA)
HU = compareDNA(humanDNA, unknownDNA)
if MU != HU and MU > HU:
    print "mouse"
elif MU != HU and MU < HU:
    print "human"
elif MU == HU:
    print "identity cannot be determined"
```

EDIT: Added the messed up part of the second function running into a similar problem.

Comment: `compareDNA()` is never used, is this intended?

Comment: Yeah i havent gotten to using this function yet because i ran into a problem with my first one already haha

Answer (score 0):

`countCodon()` has no return value so `HD = None`

Moreover from https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

> string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
>
> ```
> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.
> ```

So `countCodon()` is giving you the index where the string "ATG" first appears, not the number of times it is present.